# Warning: returning reference to local temporary (But I can guarantee it's NOT a temporary)

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, temporary

I have a function `get` which returns a reference to an object. This function is called by an other function `get2`, which forwards this reference. In `get2`, the result of `get` is considered as a temporary, which is true. BUT I can guarantee that data behind that reference is not a temporary.

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
char * buffer; // for raw binary data, will be allocated somewhere

const char& getRaw(int idx){
    return buffer[idx];
}

const int& getInt(int idx){
    return getRaw(idx);
}
```

What should I do in that case? (In the meanwhile, I can even post a solution, but as long as its on hold, I can not answer it.)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/332b1740538f4342)

Comment: The simplified code works and compiles without warnings. Try to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which have your problem.

Comment: Why is the result of "get" considered a temporary?  I see no reason for that.  I tried this in Visual Studio 2013 and there is no warning.

Comment: Are you sure in your real code that get returns a reference and not a value?

Comment: Ok, then maybe I oversimplified something. I will check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To an experienced C++ programmer, the problem should be quite obvious: I implicitly convert from char& to int& in getInt. So the compiler will create a temporary int and return a reference to it, instead of just returning the char& and re-interpret it as an int&.

A reinterpret cast helps:

```
char * buffer; // for raw binary data, will be allocated somewhere

const char& getRaw(int idx){
    return buffer[idx];
}

const int& getInt(int idx){
    return reinterpret_cast<const int&>(getRaw(idx));
}
```